# Curator Framework doesn't allow me check Connection

Tags: frameworks, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm checking the connection of a CuratorFramework instance, when i do in debug mode it passes fine, but when I do in running mode it pass through the verification considering the condition as false.

```
    curatorFramework.getZookeeperClient().isConnected();
```

Is something wrong with the code? This is how i create the instance:

```
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 1);
    CuratorFramework curatorFramework= CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(host, retryPolicy);
    curatorFramework.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't spot anything obviously wrong with your code, however, I'd suggest giving the [CuratorFrameworkFactory](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/CuratorFrameworkFactory.html) a try for building your CuratorFramework instance like so:

```
String connectionString = ....

CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder()
        .namespace("my_namespace")
        .connectString(connectionString )
        .retryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 1))
        .build();

client.start();
```

I'd also suggest testing your code with the Curator's built-in [TestingServer](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/test/TestingServer.html) to ensure the problem isn't with the ZK cluster you're currently testing against. To setup and connect to the Curator test server, simply use something like this:

```
TestingServer zkTestServer = new TestingServer(31313);

CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder()
        .namespace("my_namespace")
        .connectString(zkTestServer.getConnectString())
        .retryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 1))
        .build();

client.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should connect to zk after you start the curatorFramework using `curatorFramework.blockUntilConnected()`, and then get client and check connection status. Something likes below:

```
    ...
    curatorFramework.start();

    try {
        curatorFramework.blockUntilConnected(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (curatorFramework.getZookeeperClient().isConnected()) {
            System.out.println(curatorFramework.getState());
            return;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    ...
```